# Retrieving Kerberos from Windows to Linux

Tags: ruby, windows, linux, file-permissions

I want to make an intranet app which allows users to browse directories and download files from a Windows share.

The intranet app is currently Rails, but essentially is hosted on Ubuntu (i.e. not Windows)

The intranet app has a login, so I know the username of the current user as a string, e.g "paul". This would be the same username on the Windows box.

Is there a way to list and access files using the combination of file permissions set in Windows and the username from the web app, hosted on Linux?

I'm thinking there's perhaps something in WinBind or SMBClient (which I clearly know little about) or something like that? The key question I think, is related to being able to access Windows files permissions (including groups and membership of) from Linux.

Comment: Rewriting the question would be "retrieving `Kerberos` from windows to linux"?

Comment: Thanks @uDay I've edited the title as you suggest - now looking into Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I used the Windows utility [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) and built a simple web service on the Windows box which takes a username parameter and returns a tree of readable files as JSON which I could then easily access from the intranet Rails app.

Not awesome, but works for intranet.